# How to update URL from java code

Tags: url, jsf-2, primefaces, updates

what i am looking for is a simple way to update the browsers URL.

I have added deeplinks for my primefaces dataTables, so that:

```
some_url?filter=column:value;column:value
```

will automatically filters the dataTable on my page with the given values from url.

```
    <f:viewParam name="filter" value="#{NewsBean.items.settings.deepLink}"/>
    <h:form id="NewsForm">
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{NewsBean.items.deepLinkAction}" />

        <p:dataTable .... >
```

"deepLink" saves the String and "deepLinkAction" parses the String and filters the dataTable.

Now i want to update the URL on filtering the DataTable. When filterEvent is fired the String of "deepLink" is updated to the filtered values with the given pattern.
But how can i achieve, that the String of my deeplink is shown in the URL. I do not want to reload the page, due to double filtering and double database access.

Is there any clientside solution just to show the URL. I do not want to have another button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do this in most modern browsers.
Having prepared your new URL, you can use the pushState method as follow.

```
var newURL="/new-url";
window.history.pushState({}, "Page Title", newURL);
```

for more information you should visit [here](http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/). However, you want to do this job in your java code, so I recommend you to prepare your url in your java class, then use AJAX to transfer your url to the client side, then use pushState.